# How to get the value of a cells instead of <Cell 'Sheet1'.A2>' with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Basically I'm unable to get the value of a cell from a Excel file with openpyxl.

```py
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Inputs.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

print(sheet['A2'])
```

The column 'A' has theses values

Velocidad
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27

And instead of getting '3' I get **Cell 'Hoja1'.A2** being Hoja1 the name of the sheet.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `cell.value` where `cell` is `sheet['A2']`

Comment: See the [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#data-storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheet['A2']` is an object, namely an instance of the class `Cell` ([docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html)).

A cell object has a property `value`, so instead of

```
print(sheet['A2'])
```

use

```
print(sheet['A2'].value)
```

Here's another usage example from the docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html